# Getting a list of users with their assigned role in Identity 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, roles

I am stuck trying to get this output

```
Id | Name   | Role
----------------------------
1  | John   | Administrator
----------------------------
2  | Mary   | Manager
----------------------------
3  | Sage   | Editor
----------------------------
4  | Hank   | Manager
```

I can make it work in LINQPad, but somehow I am unable to translate it to ASP.NET MVC.

```
from u in Users
from ur in u.Roles
join r in Roles on ur.RoleId equals r.Id
select new {
    Id = u.Id,
    Name = u.Name,
    Role = r.Name,
}
```

How do I LINQ that in ASP.NET MVC 5 with Identity?

Just to be clear, I am looking for the JOIN query between Users and Roles.

Comment: Do you want this output on console or get it in index list in Razor view?

Comment: I want to return it to a View in a Controller

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using ASP.NET Identity 2, you have to add some codes to AccountContoller. Add an `ActionResult` to get `UserList`. You also nedd `ApplicationDbContext` instance and get it from `OwinContext`  :

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
    }

    public ActionResult UserList()
    {
        var applicationDbContext = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
        var users = from u in applicationDbContext.Users
                    from ur in u.Roles
                    join r in ApplicationDbContext.Roles on ur.RoleId equals r.Id
                    select new
                    {
                        u.Id,
                        Name = u.UserName,
                        Role = r.Name,
                    };

            // users is anonymous type, map it to a Model 
            return View(users);
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

**Update** - if user has multiple roles:

```
from user in applicationDbContext.Users
select new
{
    user.Id,
    user.UserName,
    Roles = applicationDbContext.Roles.Where(r => user.Roles.Select(ur => ur.RoleId).Contains(r.Id)).Select(r => r.Name)
}
```

Comment: This looks great, but what if a user has multiple roles?

Answer (score 1):

This will help you

```
    using(ApplicationDbContext db=new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
          var users = (from user in db.Users
                       from roles in user.Roles
                       join role in db.Roles
                       on roles.RoleId equals role.Id 
                       select new
                       {
                           user.UserName, 
                           role.Name
                       }).ToList(); 
    }
```